# silent post md5 on capture authorization

Tags: hash, authorize.net, silent-post

I have transactions which are held for verification and approval (prior capture). When i approve them in the merchant portal, silent post receives an immediate update, but the MD5 hash doesn't match. It seems that it's being built differently by authnet. For all other transactions (arbs and one-times) the hash matches fine.

Is there a different md5 structure for prior-capture approvals? is it documented anywhere?

Comment: [This is the best I can find.](https://support.authorize.net/authkb/index?page=content&id=A588). You might want to post at their [developer community](https://community.developer.authorize.net/) where their devs hang out.